# Why am I unable to delete a getter function from an object instance?

Tags: javascript, object, getter

I am confused as to why I am unable to delete a getter function from an object instance of a constructor function:

```
//created constructor function
let f = function () {
    this.a = 1;
    this.b = 2;   
}
    
//created an instance
let o = new f()
    
//created a getter function on object o

Object.defineProperties(o, {f: 
    {get: function(){
    return 100
    }
}})
        
//tried to delete but got response as false.
delete o.f
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only delete *configurable* properties. From MDN:

> **`configurable`**
> `true` if the type of this property descriptor may be changed and if the property may be deleted from the corresponding object. Defaults to `false`.

```js
//created constructor function
let f = function () {
    this.a = 1;
    this.b = 2;   
}
    
//created an instance
let o = new f()
    
//created a getter function on object o

Object.defineProperties(o, {
  f: {
    get: function(){
      return 100
    },
    configurable: true,
  }
})

console.log(delete o.f);
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you didn't set the `f` property as `configurable`:

```js
//created constructor function
let f = function () {
    this.a = 1;
    this.b = 2;   
}
    
//created an instance
let o = new f()
    
//created a getter function on object o

Object.defineProperties(o, {
  f: {
    get: function(){
      return 100
    },
    configurable: true
  }
});
        
//tried to delete but got response as false.
console.log(delete o.f);

console.log(o.f);
```